# How can I insert a snippet on a new line with vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'm trying to make a vscode snippet for python.
Suppose I have a line of code like this:

```
my_var = call_some_function()
```

I'd like to double click on my_var to select it, hit a key, and it produces the following result:

```
my_var = call_some_function()
LOGGER.debug("my_var: %s", my_var)
<cursor is here>
```

Also it should work for an expression too, like if I select "x + y + z" in this line and hit the key:

```
call_function(x + y + z)
```

It should produce:

```
call_function(x + y + z)
LOGGER.debug("x + y + z: %s", x + y + z)
<cursor is here>
```

Obviously using a debugger is better. But sometimes you cannot use a debugger.

Comment: somewhat close https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826623/vs-code-snippet-to-console-log-selection-beneath-current-line

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Updating the answer because you no longer need an extension to do this.  As of vscode v1.77 there is a new builtin command `runCommands` which acts like a macro and can run a series of commands.

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+d",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args":{
    "commands": [
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
      "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "snippet": "LOGGER.debug(\"$CLIPBOARD: %s\", $CLIPBOARD)\n$0"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Too bad you seemingly can't do this with snippets. I had never heard of multiCommand. Thanks!

Comment: "editor.action.jumpToBracket", *2 before "editor.action.insertLineAfter", it avoid print in objet,array :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what was asked for, but is close, using the $CLIPBOARD variable:

```
"log-clipboard": {
    "prefix": "log-clipboard",
    "body": [
        "LOGGER.debug('$CLIPBOARD: %s', $CLIPBOARD)",
        "$0"
    ],
    "description": "Log an expression from the clipboard"
}
```

To use:

1. Select what you want to log and hit Copy
2. Go to where you want the log it
3. Type log-clipboard and hit enter

Pretty close.