# Is it possible to have a snippet that considers the length of my input?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I would like to define a snippet for comments like

```
//************
//*  foo A1  *
//************
```

where I enter `foo A1` and it would create a line with (6+ len(${1}) asterisks etc. - is that doable and if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I am a big proponent of [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips) (see

[[VSCODE]: Is there a way to insert N times the same characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149126/vscode-is-there-a-way-to-insert-n-times-the-same-characters/63158335#63158335),

[VS Code: how to make a python snippet that after string or expression hitting tab will transform it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985908/vs-code-how-to-make-a-python-snippet-that-after-string-or-expression-hitting-ta/57518594#57518594) and

[VSCode Advanced Custom Snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62545965/vscode-advanced-custom-snippets/62562886#62562886) for how to use it),

it is instructive to see how to do this with just the built-in snippet functionality in vscode.  Here is a snippet that does what you want:

```
"Custom Comment": {
    "prefix": ["cc2"],    // whatever trigger you want, then tab, write your info and tab again
    "body": [
        "//***${1/./*/g}***",
        "//*  $1  *",
        "//***${1/./*/g}***"
    ]
},
```

That just adds 3 asterisks to the beginning and 3 to the end of your added comment, each character of which is replaced by an asterisk as well.

[image: custom comment demo]

Comment: Beautiful. Native. +1. “Instructive” should say “better” :) extensions are great, but not downloading one is better

Comment: Thank you - very nice, indeed - especially because it's native - as @soulshined said ;)

Comment: It is good to know HyperSnips because it is more powerful than the native snippets - able to run javascript on input for example and replace with the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extension [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips)

```
snippet comment "Comment" A
``rv = '//' + '*'.repeat(t[0].length + 6)``
//*  $1  *
``rv = '//' + '*'.repeat(t[0].length + 6)``
endsnippet
```