# Is there a shortcut for a comment followed by a line of hyphens in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I would like to find an shortcut that does something like this:

```
//-------------------------
// like above and beneath
//-------------------------
```

Comment: Note: This type of comment is not generally used in C#. Preferably use XML doc comments (type three `///`) or use regions.

Comment: Is this for Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code?  You tagged them both.

Comment: I tried to convey it was for both since I use both. I should have made it more clear, my mistake.

Comment: No problem, a lot of people get them confused and so you have to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ For VS Code: ]

Reworking the snippet from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63440555/836330, try this:

```
"Custom Comment": {
    "prefix": ["cc2"],
    "body": [
        "//-${1/./-/g}--",
        "// $1",
        "//-${1/./-/g}--"
    ]
},
```

[image: custom comment demo]

You can bind that to a shortcut too:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+r",
  "command":  "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "name": "Custom Comment"
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

---

If you already have the comment line and then later would like to wrap it as you showed, select the comment line first and then use this snippet:

```
"Custom Comment": {
    "prefix": ["cc2"],
    "body": [
      "//${TM_CURRENT_LINE/./-/g}",
      "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}",
      "//${TM_CURRENT_LINE/./-/g}",
    ]
},
```

[image: custom comment2 demo]